# Redirecting my output from a Makefile

Tags: makefile, g++, gnu-make

With my Makefile, I'm trying to get my all my objects and binaries to end up in a Release directory. Seems every permutaion I've tried has some error so I'm asking for some help. Here is what I have and I need to know how to alter it. Thanks.

```
BUILDDIR = Release
CXXFLAGS =      -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
LDFLAGS=
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
LIBS =
EXECUTABLE= MyProgram

all:  $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify these lines as follows:

```
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)

EXECUTABLE := $(BUILDDIR)/MyProgram
```

Then there are two options. The first is to use `vpath` to locate sources needed to be compiled into objects. The second is to use explicit pattern rule:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : ./%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```